# Using two values with ',' checkbox and Saving with php[code igniter] , calculating with 'Javascript'

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

My case is a bit complex so please bear with me. Here is what my form look like. I am using webservice [json instead of db] .

[image: Form]

At there I need to save 'syskey' in generating json and send to server

I need to add 'syskey' in value. Like this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="20133123123713" name="toppings[]">Black Pear
```

But I need one additional feature that is on the fly price calculation with javascript. In one of the post from stackoverflow , I learn that I can add two values to a single checkbox using ','. So I do like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="20133123123713,0.50" name="addon[]">Black Pear
```

### Please see the screenshot for more clearer picture.

[image]

---

My question now is

`I want to save value from "20133123123713,0.50" [syskey:20133123123713 only]` in php

`and use value from  "20133123123713,0.50" [price:0.50] in` javascript.

How can I achieve that? I had been searching and pulling hairs for days and is my way appropiate? Help me.

Comment: Total value calculation in javascript should be like this. (Unit price + addon+addon)*quantity . Example 4.5$ with two addons [0.5$] = 5.5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you would use `checkbox.value.split(",")[1]`

On the PHP side, what you use depends on your version:

- PHP 5.3 and older: `array_shift(explode(",",$_POST['checkbox']));`
- PHP 5.4 and newer: `explode(",",$_POST['checkbox'])[0];`

Comment: let me try and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @Prisoner That would get the syskey, not the price.

Comment: @Kolink how to save multiple checkbox value? from php side while eliminating  price value.

Comment: my previous code :// $toppings=implode(',', $_POST['toppings']);

Comment: 20133123123713,0.50,2013312312313,0.90,20133124313,0.40 || There is a pattern I might do like this  "save,skipped,save,skipped" . but how?